# Net forehand with topspin to high balls: how to practise them?

Tags: tennis, technique, training, spin

I want to improve my forehand near the net. I hit ball to a wall with a specific target but the rebound is so fast that it is not really equivalent to high ball shots. How do you train forehand near the net?

**Example**

> Topspin forehand like the [Federer below](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uFrD3Ne-Rc&t=1m11s) near the net.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a basket of balls, go out to the court, and just practice them. Give the ball a high bounce. Set a specific target to hit, like try hitting the corner sides of the service lines.